# How to display an image using Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to know how to display an image using Xcode and Objective-C. I am using Xcode 4.5.2. I would prefer to use an empty application. Thanks.

Comment: We are not a site for tutorials, nor questions that show no effort on the part of the asker.  Perhaps you could rephrase.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display an image in app.

It is as simple as this,

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

You dont need a tutorial just for this. Just go through the documentation and you can figure out rest of the properties.